# Error in first time boot

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, boot-failure

I have Windows Vista 32-bit. I already had Ubuntu Studio installed with WUBI. Now I get this error when I select Ubuntu:

```
Try (hd0,0) : NTFS5
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its a problem with root.disk. Have a look [here](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.de/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html). Hope that helps. Backup anything important before you do it.